# No sound playing on apple push notification iOS 8.1.3

Tags: ios, ios8, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios8.1

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) and set everything just like it says to receive push notifications on iOS.

I set the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in Xcode with this:

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)]) {
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil]];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

I got registered(I am able to get the deviceToken) and i can get the message from the push notification when is sent, the problem is that i can't get to play any notification sound, my pusher.php is like this:

```
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => "default" 
    );
```

I am using iOS 8.1.3

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problems, Seems like the Code below is obsolete:

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound |
                                                                                                UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                                                                UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}

if (application) {

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|
                                                       UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|
                                                       UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }
}
return YES;}
```

As I'am only getting Local notifications within the App. Even after putting correct certificate to this.
So far Iv not found any help with this, so ended up emailing Apple Developer Technical Support about this.

Comment: any luck with this issue?

Comment: Hi this is the reply I got from Apple:

Comment: I’m responding to your question about the Apple Push Notification service.
There weren’t any API changes in iOS 8.1.3 that would affect push notifications.
Did you just upgrade from the iOS 7 SDK by any chance? Requesting permission to present user notifications was separated from registering for push notifications in the iOS 8 SDK. This only affects apps that have been built with the iOS 8 SDK. Apps built with older SDKs should still work as they have before.

Comment: If you moved to the iOS 8 SDK without changing your code accordingly, you'll get a message in the console log saying that the old API is no longer supported. Take a look at Configuring the User Notification Settings and Registering for Remote Notifications for the new APIs.

Comment: thanks. Btw, I found my issue: my app notifications were disabled in settings by some magic :)